# Flask root path - app.root_path, current_app.root_path, and others do not work

Tags: python, flask

I can't believe this can be so hard. I scored the web trying to find a solution, but still cannot access the root_path of my Flask application. What's worse, in one file it works, in the other it doesn't. Here is what I tried:

```
from flask import current_app

file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(current_app.root_path, 'dir/for/my/files/'))
#  ERROR: RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

#  I added ROOT_PATH to my settings.py file
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(app.config['ROOT_PATH'], 'dir/for/my/files/'))
#  ERROR: RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(current_app.instance_path, 'dir/for/my/files/'))
#  ERROR: RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

The file above is inside my `controllers` folder. I am using the application factory pattern based on [Flask-Foundation](https://github.com/JackStouffer/Flask-Foundation).

I read the [docs about the application context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/) and I just don't get it. I tried:

```
import app
with app.app_context():
   ...
# ERROR: AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'app_context'
```

In the file I got it working, I have:

```
import app_name
@bp.route('/')
def index():
    file_path = os.path.join(app_name.app.root_path(current_app.root_path, 'dir/for/my/files/'))
```

Which seems like *not* the right way to do it. But it works. If I try the same on the other file, in the same folder, it doesn't work.

I am tearing my hair out over this... any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: This is a dumb question but did you try `file_path='/dir/for/my/files/'`

Comment: That would work but I would have to write the whole sytem absolute path, which would make the app only work in my computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It is simple.

You cannot call `current_app.config['KEY_VALUE']` on the root of the files. It should be always inside a `def` or a class definition, which is then instantiated inside a `def`.